# Sencha Touch - Store JSON file containing Array

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sencha Touch JSON Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110380/sencha-touch-json-format)

I have the following JSON file I would like to parse into my Sencha Touch application. I cannot figure out what type of "store" (Store, JsonStore, ArrayStore, etc.) to use and what the "field" setup would be like. Each "datapoint" in the array should be stored as an xValue and a yValue. I don't understand how these points can be read without individual tags...

```
[{"target": "stats.server1", "datapoints": [[22, 34], [99, 12], [13, 15], [56, 12], [34, 2], [13, 23], [23, 34], [55, 88]]},{"target": "stats.server2", "datapoints": [[22, 34], [99, 12], [13, 15], [56, 12], [34, 2], [13, 23], [23, 34], [55, 88]]}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please avoid asking the same thing even when you still responded.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110380/sencha-touch-json-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code is for Ext JS 4.1, but as far as I understand, the data framework in Touch 2 is the same.

```
// A reader defines how to process incoming data.
Ext.define('My.PointsReader', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    alias: 'reader.points',
    getData: function(data) {       // overriding
        data = this.callParent(arguments);
        var result = [];
        Ext.each(data, function(entry) {
            Ext.each(entry.datapoints || [], function(point) {
                result.push({
                    xValue: point[0], yValue: point[1],
                    target: entry.target
                });
            });
        });
        return result;
    }
});

// A store is always Ext.data.Store (or TreeStore, for trees).
// But its proxy, reader and writer can be customized.
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['xValue', 'yValue', 'target'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'test.json',
            reader: 'points'
        }
    });

store.load();
```

Comment: Thank you! How would the "target" as shown above, be integrated into this solution? Assuming there would be a target for each set of datapoints.

Comment: "target", meaning the "target" key in the JSON file

Comment: @user1467584 But in your example you only have one `target` for all `datapoints`.

Comment: My apologies...I've updated the example above to be more accurate.